# Highcharts and OpenLayers not rescaling after Bootstrap layout change

Tags: highcharts, bootstrap-4, openlayers

In my Angular 2 environment, the OpenLaysers and Highcharts components are not rescaling themself after I change the Bootstrap layout. If I click on my button that changes the Bootstrap grid classes, the components should rerender. I tried rerendering the charts through highcharts.redraw() function - that does not fix the problem. As visible in the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14UarLQTEnXpCVW9-6shsqbZZo1UEd0Uy/view?usp=sharing), if I press 'F12' and go into 'Developer Tools' (showing as a black box at the bottom - 0:08), the components redraw. Therefore I tried workarounds like giving the body a zoom of 2.0000.1, new zIndex, different height, display 'none' - 'block'. Nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

In Highcharts you should use [`chart.reflow()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow) not `chart.redraw()`. Alternatively, you can use [`chart.setSize(newWidth, newHeight)`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSize).

Comment: Thanks, that helps with the charts. Still my question somehow remains: Can I reproduce the same behavior as what happens when I open the developer tools?

Comment: When you open/close dev tools, window fires `resize` event, which by default is used in Highcharts to call `chart.reflow()`. When you resize elements, you need to manually call `chart.reflow()`. Unfortunately, I'm don't know how to fix this in OpenLayers.

Comment: The OpenLayers function would be `map.updateSize()`
I am still not satisfied with this 'by hand' solution. Thanks so much anyway.

Comment: There's no **reliable** native event that works across browsers to determine that an HTML element was re-rendered.